Disk cloning or mirroring technology for on a running Linux OS or Windows OS?
part1
Is there a technology for disk cloning and backup on a running Linux OS or windows OS?

Clonezill: the operating system running the business must be stopped,
booted from a live CD, and then the disk cloned, which can have
significant downtime
drbd: can be installed on the running operating
system, but the metadata cannot be written on a disk with an existing file system, additional clean disks must be prepared to store the metadata
dd: can be used on a running operating system, but must
ensure that the file system is unmounted, making it impossible to
clone the system disk
ddrescue: is generally not recommended for cloning mounted filesystems, as it can lead to data inconsistencies
and potential data corruption.
rsync: Migration based on file level is slow and efficient
Windows vss: I haven't have time to learn about this.

I am researching host migration methods, the most basic requirement is in the case of not stopping the source business system, across any platform to complete the host migration, and support for full, incremental and differential data migration of disk blocks.
it is clear that the use of Clonezill such as this leads to a long period of downtime of the tool is unacceptable to the customer, I would like to know whether there are other programs can be achieved in the disk online migration of the technology?
The basic principle is probably to install some kind of tool in the source host, boot the target via LIVE CD or PE, save the transferred disk data, and reboot after the migration is complete.
part2
The names of the technologies I found relevant to this may be as follows:

Hot Clone/Live Clone/Cold Clone
Changed Block Tracking (VMware CBT)

Also I found a similar golang project on github:
https://github.com/benjojo/hot-clone
and it says:
This tool allows you to image an actively changing block device. Including the one the rootfs is stored on.
This is very similar to what I want and I'm still researching it.

There is no such tool in general. If your system already has ZFS, you can leverage it's snapshots and send-receive technique that is very close to what you want. Another close tool is rsync (which you mentioned) and it's what I did in a similar situation; first sync online, possibly inconsistent, and then stop the services and quickly rsync a difference to attain a consistent state.

I know of at least one free/paid tool I use on Windows that also exists for Linux, but we don't recommend products here.

@Zac67 the problem is, Linux has no provision for such tool to be possible. There is no system call to freeze all the filesystems at once or to make a bunch of snapshots atomically. One can indeed claim their tool is "like in Windows", but it won't be exactly like, it can't possibly have the same features.

@NikitaKipriyanov I understand that and don't know how they do it (they mention a kernel module), but they claim bare-metal recovery and changed block tracking, just like with their Windows tool.

Windows can leverage native backup technology for this. Unfortunately, I don't believe Linux has parity in this regard. Using Windows, a backup of a physical host can be restored to physical or virtual hardware, and same for a virtual source. Given that most hosts are virtual these days, you may want to go up a level and limit your attempt to hypervisors. For example, if you use KVM find a solution that works for that virtualization platform.

The key problem always is the amount of time it takes to make a backup, to copy the contents of the disk. With today's terabyte disks that can take a great deal of time. The only way of doing this, without stopping the system, that I have seen is to use the Linux RAID system: use mdadm to create a RAID1 mirror of the disk of interest, then when it's fully synced stop the backup disk and remove it from the array. Of course mdadm will then show the array as degraded, which makes it the perfect time to drop in the disk for the next backup and start the sync.
I'm well aware that this is not the intended use of RAID1, but as far as I know it's the only way to do a full backup without stopping the running system. It's much safer, of course, to cleanly shut down the system when you have sync, pull the backup disk with the system down, and restart; that way all the files are properly closed.

Probably this can be made with HW RAIDs as well (For instance, I think I can arrange this with MegaRAID). However, this is not only "not intended" use of RAID1, but somewhat defeats the purpose of having RAID. And, while looking clever, it'll help only in case the whole (active) system storage is a single array; if not, the synchronization issue (a.k.a. impossibility of simultaneously and atomically snapshotting several volumes at once) will arise in full and this would be the least preferred solution due to hazards associated.

When you are running linux on xfs you could clone your running OS with xfsdump and xfsrestore to another disk (used for fast irix installations earlier, just updated /etc/sys_id for other host). If you want to use the cloned disk later for another host you have to correct the generated network interface uuid's, hostname etc dependend on hw.
